# Tree Structure and XML

Tags: java, jquery, xml, tree

I need to store a user created folder structure to an xml file . I think allowing that using a tree strucure is a best option .Iwill be using java and  [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/demo) for this .  When user saves data I will be passing all options to a jsp file as json and save that as xml file .

Any one can suggest me if there is any better approach ?

I hope that I am posting this question in right place .

Comment: How is a list of user events a tree?

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry , I edited my question . Basically it was a workflow which user will create which looks  like a folder structure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how jsTree works (I haven't looked at it much), it may be just as easy to serialize everything straight to XML instead of to JSON. That way you avoid the hassle of converting from JSON to XML in the Java code. If you go this route, you may even be able to avoid the server-side processing at all, and instead generate the file directly from the javascript. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file) question for options on accomplishing this.

Other than that, seems like a good plan to me.